# Apache Redirecting - Image files

Tags: image, apache, redirect

Im having problems with the Apache's redirect.

I triying to redirect a request for a image file , I tried to use the same sintax used for pages. but it doesn't work

I'm doing this:

```
Redirect 301 /images/hamb.jpg http://my-website/denny.png
```

When I say it doesn't work is because the result is a 404 error - I tried to redirect the request because the jpg file is no longer available. Other redirects works but are page redirects. There is no error in the url.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @user542824: it should would are you 100% sure of the source URI.

Comment: yah, when you say "doesn't work", what actually happens?

Comment: When I say it doesn't work is because the result is a 404 error - I tried to redirect the request because the jpg file is no longer available. Other redirects works but are page redirects. There is no error in the url. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you check if the 404 error is for the original request or http://my-website/denny.png. That is, is the redirect actually happening but denny.png is not accessible.

Comment: the http://my-website/denny.png works ok, even in my production site the redirect doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I check the url in my production site and it was wrong. THANKS

Conclusion:

Is the same rule to redirect a file in apache